# Oracle C++ connection without installing the Oracle client or instant client

Tags: c++, oracle, database-connection

I've used some Oracle tools which do not require any installation of the Oracle client or instant client, require no modification of paths, or setup of ODBC data sources, or tnsnames.ora files.

I would like to know how this is done. For example, oracmd (http://www.withdata.com/oracmd.html) connects to Oracle without any additional client tools. So we know it's possible.

Basically I would like to create an R package which can read a SQL file and take the ip address, port and SID/Service Name as arguments and return the data. The only installation necessary is to install the R package. I would prefer free/open source license to distribute the package.

I was able to build an R package to do this using JDBC without a client, but the performance was terrible for data sets of > 1000 rows. I am looking for something better than JDBC.

Comment: Those applications most likely ship with some Oracle DLL.

Comment: You should implement TNS :-)

Comment: At least on Linux/Unix it is possible to link libclntst.a statically.

Answer (score 3):

There are a handful of companies that have reverse engineered the Oracle network protocol so that they don't need to include any sort of client software.  Normally, these are companies that implement things like wire protocol ODBC drivers.  Since the Oracle network protocol is undocumented and subject to change across releases, this is generally not a trivial undertaking-- you're talking dozens if not hundreds of man-years of effort.

The vast majority of applications like the one you link to will either be using JDBC behind the scenes and will include the thin JDBC driver or will be installing the Instant Client transparently as part of the installation process.  The whole point of the Instant Client was to allow application developers to bundle it with their applications so that the application install could set up the Oracle client software as well.

All that being said, the premise that you need to abandon JDBC because of performance issues and that using C++ would produce substantial performance improvements seems suspect to me.  If done correctly, a JDBC application ought to pull data just as quickly as a C++ application.  The bottleneck really ought to be the ability of the database to run the query and the network's ability to transmit the data.  It's certainly possible to write naive JDBC code that produces very poor performance but that is more an application programming issue than an API issue.